# Spark Dataframe - Best way to cogroup dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I currently load CSV files into Dataframes using the databricks library.

I'm looking for the best generic approach to cogroup my loaded dataframes using a specific key since the cogroup operation is only available for PairRDDs.

I found this post which implements a cogroup feature for Dataframes but I guess there are some different approaches :

https://gist.github.com/ahoy-jon/b65754cde98cc48b9b38

Have you please ever faced this situation ?

Thanks.

Comment: How to use `cogroup` for large datasets like when I use `collect()` it throws out of memory exception `rdd1 = rdd2.cogroup(rdd3).collect`. Can you help on this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180307/how-to-use-cogroup-for-large-datasets]. can partitioning help I'm new to spark any help to resolve this.