# How can create other dataframe with third column contains an array of second dataframe filtered by id of first dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have two data frames with people addresses.
A table contains reliable sources of addresses and other untrusted sources addresses.
We want to know what is the provability that the address is the real person.

I'm using **Spark 1.5**

I have **two dataframes**:

**DF1**

```
COL1  | COL2 
00001 | Street 1    
00001 | Street 2    
00002 | Street 1    
00002 | Street 2    
00002 | Street 1
```

**DF2**

```
COL1  | COL2   
00001 | Street 1    
00001 | Street 2    
00001 | Street 2    
00001 | Street 2    
00002 | Street 1    
00002 | Street 2    
00002 | Street 1
```

My question is how can convert to this dataframe / map / other? I mean to convert into something like the following piece of code.

```
COL1  | COL2        | COL3 (Array or Vector)   
00001 | Street 1    | [00001 | Street 1, 00001 | Street 2, 00001 | Street 2, 00001 | Street 2]    
00001 | Street 2    | [00001 | Street 1, 00001 | Street 2, 00001 | Street 2, 00001 | Street 2]    
00002 | Street 1    | [00002 | Street 1, 00002 | Street 2, 00002 | Street 1]    
00002 | Street 2    | [00002 | Street 1, 00002 | Street 2, 00002 | Street 1]   
00002 | Street 1    | [00002 | Street 1, 00002 | Street 2, 00002 | Street 1]
```

This last table is just an example, i need to join the both dataframes independent of the table of file format. Our necessity is process data of the third table for obtain statistics.

Comment: In this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806473/spark-dataframe-best-way-to-cogroup-dataframes) there is a possible solution but It consists of creating RDDs from the dataframe, cogrouping them, then converting them back to data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the below code using spark 1.6.

I've Written the solution assuming that COL1 is a String.

#### STEPS:

1. Convert `DF1` to RDD[(String,String)]
2. Group `DF2` by `COL1`
3. Join the result of `Step-1` with `Step-2`
4. Map the result from `Step-3` to `RDD[Row]`
5. Define the Struct
6. Create a new DataFrame

#### CODE:

```
val aggRDD = df1.rdd.map(r=>         // Converting DF1 to RDD[(String,String)]
  (r.getString(0),                   //Mapping COL1
    r.getString(1))                  //Mapping COL2
).join(                              //Joining DF1 with grouped DF2 
  df2.rdd.groupBy(r=>r.getString(0)) // Grouping DF2 by COL1
).map(r=>                            // r -> (String, (String, Iterable[Row]))
  Row.fromSeq(Seq(                   // Creating a Row Object
    r._1,                            // Setting COL1
    r._2._1,                         // Setting COL2
    r._2._2.map(i=>                  // Converting the Row object to String
      i.getString(0)+"|"+i.getString(1) // Extracting COL1 and COL2 Value
    )
  ))
)

// Defining the Struct for the new DataFrame
val struct = new StructType(Array(
    StructField("COL1",StringType,nullable = true),
    StructField("COL2",StringType,nullable = true),
    StructField("Array",
    ArrayType(StringType,containsNull = true),nullable = true)
))    

// Creating a new DataFrame from RDD[Row]
val df = sq.createDataFrame(aggRDD,struct)

df.show(truncate=false)

+-----+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|COL1 |COL2    |Array                                                           |
+-----+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|00002|Street 1|[00002|Street 1, 00002|Street 2, 00002|Street 1]                |
|00002|Street 2|[00002|Street 1, 00002|Street 2, 00002|Street 1]                |
|00002|Street 1|[00002|Street 1, 00002|Street 2, 00002|Street 1]                |
|00001|Street 1|[00001|Street 1, 00001|Street 2, 00001|Street 2, 00001|Street 2]|
|00001|Street 2|[00001|Street 1, 00001|Street 2, 00001|Street 2, 00001|Street 2]|
+-----+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```